# Posts2Posts plugin and wp user frontend connect programmatically

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-posts-to-posts

I have a page (custom_post_type_A) with a form (from plugin wp user frontend, create custom_post_type_B) in this page.

When (in frontend) user insert value in the form i want an action wordpress for CONNECT (with Posts2Posts plugin) CPT_A with CPT_B.

I use in my functions.php:

```
function my_connection_collette_types() {
p2p_register_connection_type( array(
    'name' => 'CPT_A_to_CPT_B',
    'from' => 'CPT_A',
    'to' => 'CPT_B'
) );
}
add_action( 'p2p_init', 'my_connection_collette_types' );
```

This work in backend of wordpress.

Now, i want, after user submit form, create action hook for programmatically connect 2 post.

```
function connect_cpt_A_cpt_B($post_id) {
$id_CPT_A=$post_id;
$id_CPT_B=??????????
p2p_type( 'my_connection_collette_types' )->connect( $id_CPT_A, $id_CPT_B, array('date' => current_time('mysql')) );
}
add_action( 'wpuf_add_post_after_insert', 'connect_cpt_A_cpt_B' );
```

In this function i know $id_CPT_A (is $post_id value), but, i dont know $id_CPT_B. This value is the $post-id of the main page where i have the form.
How i can retrieve and transmite this value to function?

Answer (score 0):

OK, i resolved this:

simply $id_CPT_B is $_POST['page_id'].

Thx